# Windows batch script for selecting drive depent on label

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a Windows batch script that is run locally on a number of Windows 10 client PCs on system startup. The script needs to select a specific drive dependent on the label (PHILLIPS) and then copy some files to it. I tried looping through all possible drive letters C,D,E, etc and compare the volume name with the string "PHILLIPS", but it doesnt work for some reason. I also tried different functions like :GetLabel for getting the Name of a volume.

Here is my attempt:

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions
for %d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    set target_=%d:
    ::
    call :vol %target_% label_
    if /i "%label_%" == "%PHILIPS%" (
        echo %%d%
        xcopy \\SATVIE017\Softlib\philips\dpm8000-dpm8200-dpm8500_fwf_2.02.dpm target_\
        endlocal & goto :EOF
    )
)
```

It's my first time writing a batch script, so i dont know exactely what to look for solving this problem. Any advice would be very much welcomed as i dont want to to manually deploy the files on 100+ clients.

Comment: you mean the actual Volume label of the drive?

Comment: I'm going to guess the volume label reported here with DIR... Mine has none ;)    C:\Users\klindberg\Source>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 0E6E-EE7B

Comment: `for %d` in a batch file you must use `%%d`

Comment: I mean the Name of the drive, like this: https://s13.postimg.org/3sypjn2o7/Unbenannt.png
The letter is E, the Name is PHILLIPS. The Letter my vary on the clients, another device may have it assigned, but the name is always PHILIPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
vol %%a:
for /f "tokens=1-5*" %%1 in ('vol %%a:') do (
   if "%%6"=="Philips" set "vol=%%6"
 )
)
echo I found: %vol%
```

Where you will replace `echo I found: %vol%` with your actual commands.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thankl you so much you saved me a lot of work!

Answer (score 0):

Why opening every possible drive letter?

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==:" %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk where volumename^="Philips" get name /value') do set "volume=%%a:"
echo your volume is %volume%
```

Note: I used one of several possible tricks to avoid the ugly `wmic` line endings.

Comment: technically he didn't even open every possible drive letters because A and B are also valid drives and not only used for floppies

Comment: @luvuvinhphuc technically this is a better method. The other method I posted does indeed do `vol` on on each of the drives in the list.

Answer (score 0):

…and a similar idea using `MountVol`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "_target="
For /F "Delims=\ " %%A In ('"MountVol|Find ":\""'
) Do Vol %%A 2>Nul|Find /I "PHILIPS" && (Set "_target=%%A\" & GoTo Done)
If Not Defined _target Exit /B
:Done
XCopy "<Source>" "%_target%" /<Options>
```